# Searching a listbox using a bool method from another class. Getting 'not all code paths return a value'. Any idea why?

Tags: c#, class, methods, listbox, boolean

More details at the bottom of this. My code:

Form class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ShoppingBasket myBasket = new ShoppingBasket();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myBasket.IsProductInBasket("Apples"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No");
        }
    }
}
```

OrderItem class:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; } 
    public decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalOrder { get; set; }

    public OrderItem(string productName, decimal latestPrice, int quantity)
    {
        ProductName = productName;
        LatestPrice = latestPrice;
        Quantity = quantity;
        TotalOrder = latestPrice * quantity;
    }
}
```

Shopping class:

```
public class ShoppingBasket : List<OrderItem>
{
    public ShoppingBasket()
    {

    }

    public Form1 fm1;

    public bool IsProductInBasket(string productName) //Error of " 'ShoppingBasket.IsProductInBasket(string)': not all code paths return a value"
    {
        if (fm1.lstCart.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fm1.lstCart.Items.Count; i++) // Warning of 'Unreachable code detected'
            {
                if (fm1.lstCart.Items[i].ToString().Contains(productName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting that error? IsProductInBasket will always return true or false, there can never be a negative amount of values in the listbox, so if the count is 0 it returns false, if it is any more it goes through the listbox and returns true if it finds it and false if it doesn't.

Comment: Where have you initialized frm1?

Comment: @EhsanUllah I thought "public Form1 fm1;" initialized it? How would I initialize it? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You need to learn more about object-oriented programming.  You also need to understand how your loop (fails to) work.

Comment: I'm new to OO programming so yes I do, any suggestions on the best way to learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `if` statement returns true, but the loop has nothing to iterate over, your method will never return anything.
This could happen if another thread modifies the list.

You should get rid of the outer `if` / `else` entirely and simply `return false` after the loop.

Also, you don't want to `return false` in the inner `else`.
Right now, if the first product doesn't match, your loop will stop immediately, without checking the other items.

Comment: How would I make it so the loop has something to iterate over?

Comment: You don't.  Instead, you fix your code to return a value even if the loop doesn't run.  Read the rest of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This are couple of errors in your code. frm1 isn't initialized anywhere in the code. You will get exception here

```
 if (fm1.lstCart.Items.Count > 0) //Object reference
```

And you should change your code like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < fm1.lstCart.Items.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (fm1.lstCart.Items[i].ToString().Contains(productName))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
   return false;
```

Comment: Does "public Form1 fm1;" not initialise it? And if not, how would I? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: @liam.burns: No; that declares a field, which will be equal to `null`.  You need to pass the form to the constructor and set the field.

Comment: However, this problem has nothing to do with the compiler error.

Comment: it will always be null in your code. Are you initializing it like frm1 = new Form1() anywhere in your code?

Comment: @EhsanUllah: That will not do what he wants; he doesn't want a new form.

Comment: @SLaks so like 'Form1 frm1 = new Form1()'? Would I do that anywhere in the ShoppingBasket class?

Comment: @EhsanUllah when I double click on the warning it highlights the i in the i++. If that's any help?

Comment: @EhsanUllah no I'm not doing that anywhere in the code, should I do it anywhere in the SHoppingBasket class?

Comment: @EhsanUllah: That's because of the second problem in my answer; the loop always returns from the first iteration.